# Pass an JavaScript object to a HIDDEN input field, and catch it as an array/object on the Server-Side

Tags: php, javascript, arrays, object, hidden-field

I have a field on my page, like this:

```
<input type="hidden" name="myField" id="myField" />
```

and I have a piece of code that looks like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var myObject = {
        item1: 'item1 value',
        item2: 'item2 value',
        item3: 'item3 value',
        item4: 'item4 value',
    };

    $('#myField').val(myObject);
});
```

And when I submit this form, I catch and ouput the `$_POST` variable with print_r/var_dump functions and I get the following output for this Form Field (myField).

```
[myField] => [object Object]
```

How can I throw an JavaScript array/object to a form field and to have it evaluated/converted to a propper data-type on the server-side, so I could get it like this in my PHP script:

```
[myField] => Array(
    item1 => item1 value
    item2 => item2 value
    item3 => item3 value
    item4 => item4 value
)
```

How to achive this, without hard coding?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Encode the object as [JSON *<sup>[Wikipedia]</sup>*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Json):

```
$('#myField').val(JSON.stringify(myObject));
```

and decode it at the server side with [`json_decode` *<sup>[docs]</sup>*](http://php.net/manual/es/function.json-decode.php).

The [`JSON` *<sup>[docs]</sup>*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/json) object is available in [recent browsers](http://caniuse.com/json) and can also be included as [library](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js).

Comment: For `python` users - the decoding function on the server side would be [`json.loads()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html)